# How should I copy objects between two KiokuDB dirs?

Tags: perl, serialization, moose, kiokudb

I would like to make sure I get KiokuDB's `scope` concept correctly.

Suppose I would like to load an object from db1 and store it in db2. Must I have both scopes 'open' at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, any time you are working with a KiokuDB db, you need to have the scope open.